# Faster way to find the last updated timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I expect this call

```
Model.maximum(:updated_at)
```

to be faster than this one

```
Model.order(:updated_at).last.updated_at
```

Is anyone able to confirm this assertion? and, if true, explain why?

Comment: Your second query triggered an error `undefined method order for #<Array:0x00000004e20af0>` for me.

Comment: @Pavan You are right, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [the Benchmark module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to investigate easily, e.g.:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 50000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('maximum') { n.times.do; v1; end }
  x.report('order-pluck') { n.times do; v2; end }
end

def v1
  clear_cache
  Model.maximum(:updated_at)
end

def v2
  clear_cache
  Model.order(:updated_at).pluck(:updated_at).last
end

def clear_cache
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.clear
end
```

To make it worth doing this with n > 1 you'll have to clear the various caches that might be involved. There may well be a cache in your db server, separate from the ActiveRecord cache. For instance to clear the Mysql cache you could call:

```
`mysql mydb -e 'RESET QUERY CACHE'`
```

Comment: Thank you. The benchmark module is a great help, even if it does not explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is correct.

When you call `Model.maximum(:updated_at)`, you ask your DB to return just a single value.

When you call `Model.order(:updated_at).pluck(:updated_at).last`, your database returns you all the values for the `updated_at` column in the table, which consumes more memory (because you have to build a big array), and takes more time.

Comment: What if I select just one column? Model.select(:updated_at).order(:updated_at).last.updated_at

Comment: I think it depends then, on whether there is an index or this column or not, how many entries is in your table. But in general there should be no big difference then.